# Adding values to timer in Swift

Tags: swift, timer

I am creating a game where the user scores, the timer countdown need to be updated to add 2 seconds to it. I cannot seem to get this working. Other solutions online says that I need to invalidate the current timer and create a new one. How can I do that? The timer starts at 15 seconds, and I need to add 2 seconds in an if condition statement.

```
@objc func counter(){
    seconds -= 1
    countDownLabel.text = String(seconds)

    if (seconds == 0){
        timer.invalidate()
    }
}

func updatetimer(){
    seconds += 2
}

func activatetimer(){
    timer = Timer.scheduledTimer(timeInterval: 1, target: self, selector: #selector(ViewController.counter), userInfo: nil, repeats: true)
}
```

Comment: You don't need to invalidate the timer. Remove the `invalidate` line from `updateTimer` and it should work. Does it not?

Comment: It updates but not for 2 seconds. It increases by a lot more. Why?

Comment: How can I get the timer to update by increasing it for 2 seconds? Btw I updated the code to remove the invalidate.

Comment: What is "a lot more"?

Comment: Stop thinking of the `Timer` as the key, you need to keep track of how long the timer has been running and the total amount of time time `Timer` should run for, that way you can just keep increasing the duration and not care

Comment: On first try, it adds 2 seconds, then after that like 15-20 seconds. MadProgrammer: Please take note that my timer is decreasing. What should I do now?

Comment: @NawfaalMangou I can't begin to tell you how irrelevant that is (up/down it's just the difference in time)

Answer (score 1):

I recommend to use a `DispatchSource` timer which can be restarted reliably right **before** adding the seconds. If the number of seconds just has expired nothing will happen.

```
var timer : DispatchSourceTimer?

func activatetimer() {
    if timer != nil { return }
    timer = DispatchSource.makeTimerSource(queue: DispatchQueue.global())
    timer!.schedule(deadline:.now() + .seconds(1), repeating: 1.0)
    timer!.setEventHandler {
         self.seconds -= 1
         DispatchQueue.main.async {
             self.countDownLabel.text = String(self.seconds)
         }
         if self.seconds == 0 {
            self.timer?.cancel()
            self.timer = nil
         }
    }
    timer!.resume()
}

func updatetimer(){
    if let timer = timer {
        timer.schedule(deadline:.now() + .seconds(1), repeating: 1.0)
        seconds += 2
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you for helping but it is the same, when updating the timer, it adds 10+ seconds. What is causing this? On first try calling updateTimer(), it works, but after that it adds 10 to 15 seconds to the timer. :(

Comment: How often is `updatetimer` called and are there other places where `seconds` is modified?

Comment: My game has three buckets, each time a ball enters the correct bucket, my timer needs to be updated. And no seconds is not modified. Just initialised to 15 seconds at the beginning of the program.

Answer (score 1):

The `Timer` is not the key to the problem, the `Timer` is simply an opportunity to "check" how long it's been running.

The real key is knowing how long the `Timer` has been running and how long it should be allowed to run (ie the duration), from this you can calculate how much time is left.

This then allows you to change the duration without having to do anything else.

> Please take note that my timer is decreasing

Which is irrelevant.  Basically you have several pieces of information...

You know: When the `Timer` was started
You can calculate: The amount of time the timer has been running (the difference between the start time and now)
You can calculate: The remaining time (difference between running time and the allowable duration)

It's all just basic time/duration functionality.  The `Timer` just provides you means to "check" periodically how long the timer has been running

... As "rough" example...

```
var startedAt: Date?
var duration: TimeInterval = 5.0

var timer: Timer?

// This is just the label you want to update
@IBOutlet weak var durationLabel: UILabel!

// Convince duration formatter
var durationFormatter: DateComponentsFormatter = {
    let formatter = DateComponentsFormatter()
    formatter.allowedUnits = [.second]
    formatter.unitsStyle = .abbreviated
    return formatter
}()

// Stop the clock   
func stop() {
    timer?.invalidate()
    timer = nil
    startedAt = nil
}

// Start the clock
func start() {
    stop() // Just make sure
    startedAt = Date()
    timer = Timer.scheduledTimer(timeInterval: 0.5, target: self, selector: #selector(tick(_:)), userInfo: nil, repeats: true)
}

// The check in
@objc func tick(_ timer: Timer) {
    // Is the timer running? 
    guard let startedAt = startedAt else {
        stop()
        return
    }
    // How long has the timer been running
    let runningTime = Date().timeIntervalSince(startedAt)
    // Has time run out yet
    if runningTime >= duration {
        durationLabel.text = "Time ran out"
        stop()
    } else {
        // Update the label with the remaining amount of time...
        durationLabel.text = durationFormatter.string(from: duration - runningTime)
    }
}

// Add more time to the duration...
@IBAction func moreTime(_ sender: Any) {
    duration += 2.0
}
```

## Playground example...

This is slightly modified version used to test the idea in Playground

```
import UIKit 
import PlaygroundSupport

class Clock {
    
    var startedAt: Date?
    var duration: TimeInterval = 10.0
    
    var timer: Timer?
    
    var durationFormatter: DateComponentsFormatter = {
        let formatter = DateComponentsFormatter()
        formatter.allowedUnits = [.second]
        formatter.unitsStyle = .abbreviated
        return formatter
    }()
    
    func stop() {
        timer?.invalidate()
        timer = nil
        startedAt = nil
    }
    
    func start() {
        stop()
        startedAt = Date()
        timer = Timer.scheduledTimer(timeInterval: 1.0, target: self, selector: #selector(tick(_:)), userInfo: nil, repeats: true)
    }
    
    @objc func tick(_ timer: Timer) {
        report()
    }
    
    func report() {
        guard let startedAt = startedAt else {
            stop()
            return
        }
        let runningTime = Date().timeIntervalSince(startedAt)
        print(">> Duration = \(duration); Running time = \(runningTime)")
        if runningTime >= duration {
            print("Time ran out")
            PlaygroundPage.current.needsIndefiniteExecution = false
            stop()
        } else {
            print(durationFormatter.string(from: duration - runningTime))
        }
    }
    
    func moreTime(_ sender: Any) {
        duration += 2.0
    }
    
}

PlaygroundPage.current.needsIndefiniteExecution = true
let clock = Clock()
clock.start()
DispatchQueue.main.asyncAfter(wallDeadline: .now() + 2.0) {
    print("++")
    clock.moreTime("")
    clock.report()
    DispatchQueue.main.asyncAfter(wallDeadline: .now() + 2.0) {
        print("++")
        clock.moreTime("")
        clock.report()
    }
}
```

When I run it, it outputs...

```
>> Duration = 10.0; Running time = 1.0034409761428833
Optional("8s")
>> Duration = 10.0; Running time = 2.0030879974365234
Optional("7s")
++
>> Duration = 12.0; Running time = 2.018252968788147
Optional("9s")
>> Duration = 12.0; Running time = 3.002920985221863
Optional("8s")
>> Duration = 12.0; Running time = 4.002920985221863
Optional("7s")
++
>> Duration = 14.0; Running time = 4.035009980201721
Optional("9s")
>> Duration = 14.0; Running time = 5.003154993057251
Optional("8s")
>> Duration = 14.0; Running time = 6.002910017967224
Optional("7s")
>> Duration = 14.0; Running time = 7.002930045127869
Optional("6s")
>> Duration = 14.0; Running time = 8.003202080726624
Optional("5s")
>> Duration = 14.0; Running time = 9.002938032150269
Optional("4s")
>> Duration = 14.0; Running time = 10.002840995788574
Optional("3s")
>> Duration = 14.0; Running time = 11.002991080284119
Optional("2s")
>> Duration = 14.0; Running time = 12.002726078033447
Optional("1s")
>> Duration = 14.0; Running time = 13.003712058067322
Optional("0s")
>> Duration = 14.0; Running time = 14.002851009368896
Time ran out
```

As you can see, each time `moreTime` is called (look for the `++` output), 2 seconds is added to the `duration`.  The `Clock` started with 10 seconds, but ended up running a total of `14` seconds

Comment: It works yes, but when I try to update twice in a session, the second time it adds more than 10 seconds to the timer. Why is that happening?

Comment: No idea, in my testing I got between 1 & 2 seconds

Comment: Let me explain in details what is happening. I have three buckets in my game, whenever I throw the ball and scores a point, I just put duration += 2 there. Meaning each time I need to add 2 seconds when I throw in the correct bucket. The first throw, it is working as expected, the following ones, it is adding more than 2 seconds to my timer. :(

Comment: If all you're doing is adding to the `duration`, then it should work, as it's just the difference between two points in time